# ScrollView auto scrolls to selectable TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, scrollview

I have a vertical `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. Everything was ok till setting the third `TextView` in `LinearLayout` `selectable`.

After this change it auto scrolls to the third TextView.

What can cause the problem?

**Before** and **after** the change:

[image] [image]

**the layout**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/roota_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.saliherikci.poemnotebook.ReadPoemActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/poemTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Çanakkale Şehitlerine"
                android:textColor="@color/poem_title"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/poemAuthorTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Mehmet Akif ERSOY"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="11dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/poemContentTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Şu Boğaz harbi nedir? Var mı ki dünyâda eşi? "
                android:textColor="@color/poem_content"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fontSizeView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:background="@color/font_size_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:text="YAZI BOYUTU"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:dividerPadding="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:showDividers="middle" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/font_size_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_font_size_black_1_active" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/font_size_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_font_size_black_2_inactive" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/font_size_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_font_size_black_3_inactive" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/font_size_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_font_size_black_4_inactive" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/font_size_5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_font_size_black_5_inactive" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you print out what's in your layout xml file?

Comment: I didn't seee any ScrollView in your layout xml. Did you add the ScrollView programmatically?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're automatically scrolling to your third `TextView` because `SrollView` makes a call to [`ScrollView.scrollToChild` upon `ViewParent.requestChildFocus`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ScrollView.java#L1390).

[As per the docs is](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent#requestChildFocus(android.view.View,%20android.view.View)):

> Called when a child of this parent wants focus

When you use `android:textIsSelectable="true"`, you're essentially calling [`TextView.setTextIsSelectable(true)`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L4908), which makes calls to both `View.setFocusable` and `View.setFocusableInTouchMode`.

In short, to stop from automatically scrolling to your third `TextView`, give the first one some focus.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/poemTitleTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:text="Çanakkale Şehitlerine"
    android:textColor="@color/poem_title"
    android:textSize="24dp"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
@Override
    protected int computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen(Rect rect) {
        return 0;
    }
When called requestChildFocus will not called scrollToChild()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a `ScrollView` which had one `TextView` as child with marginTop (or parent paddingTop or some space).

On first click on `TextView`, the `ScrollView` would scroll the child at the top.

To avoid this jump I request focus on the child and scroll back to `y=0`

```
textView.post {
    textView.requestFocus()
    scrollView.scrollY = 0
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you try removing this attribute from poemContentTextView (your third TextView)?

> android:layout_weight="22.14"

Comment: I removed it, it is irrelevant to this problem.